# Firefox SDK current link in panel

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am currently creating a Firefox add-on using the Firefox SDK and want the url of the current tab inside a panel.

```
//index.js
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "ESURL",
  label: "Shorten this page",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: "./menu.html",
  contentScriptFile: "./menu.js",
  onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
  var curtab = tabs.activeTab;
  console.log(curtab.url+" is Opened.");//Testing
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}

//menu.html
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ESURL</h1>
    <h3>Shorten this page</h3>
    <form>
        <input id="link" type="text" value="{LINK}" disabled /><!-- Want the link here -->
        <input type="submit" value="Shorten" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is currently what i have.
How could i get the current page url and display it in "menu.html #link"?

Kind Regards,

Sven Arends

Comment: I know about page-workers but how could I combine it with a panel.

Comment: `document.location` Shows the add-on url and not the webpage url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help:

```
// Get the url of the current tab
var tabUrl = tabs.activeTab.url;

// Send a message to the panel with the url
panel.port.emit("url", tabUrl);
```

Then, on your **menu.js**:

```
// When the message arrives
self.port.on("url", function(url){

    var link = document.getElementById("link");
    link.textContent = url;
}
```

Source:

[Tabs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#url)

[Content Sripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts)

Comment: Thanks! it works :)
i surrounded `var tabUrl...` and `panel.port...` with `panel.on("show", function(e) { /*Code*/ }`